# Undefined offset in an foreach loop

Tags: php

I am having a nightmare with a Foreach loop on my site.

The error I am getting is :

> Message: Undefined offset: 0

What I would like to do is ideally check that their is a match of course & category, If their isnt not show the accordion.

An output of my Data is as follows....

> Array
>   (
>       [0] => stdClass Object
>           (
>               [course_id] => 2
>               [course_title] => Make Or Break 1 Starting Your Business
>               [course_description] => Make or Break, Starting your business.
>               [course_cost] => 35.99
>               [delivery_method_id] => 1
>               [subcategory_id] => 1
>               [course_duration] => 2 Hours
>               [course_level] => Intermediate
>               [date_added] => 2013-06-14 09:57:49
>               [date_edited] => 
>               [status] => active
>           )
>         )

However I am also getting an empty array :

> Array
>   (
>   )

My Code is as follows :

```
<div class="row">
<div class="span12">


    <h1><span class="green"><?=$category_details[0]->category_title; ?></span></h1>

    <p><?=$category_details[0]->category_description; ?></p>

    <? if(empty($courses[0][0])) { ?>
    <p>Their are currently no courses in this category.</p>
    <? } else { ?>

    <p>Courses in <?=$category_details[0]->category_title; ?></p>

    <div class="accordion-content">
        <? foreach($subcategories as $subcategory) : ?>
            <h3><a href="#"><?=$subcategory->subcategory_title; ?></a></h3>
                <div>
                    <? foreach($courses as $course): ?>
                        <? if($course[0]->subcategory_id == $subcategory->subcategory_id) { ?>
                        <ul class="accordion-course">
                            <? foreach($course as $course): ?>
                            <li>
                                    <a href="<?=base_url(); ?>view-course/<?=$course->course_id; ?>" title="View Course - <?=$course->course_title; ?>">
                                        <?=$course->course_title; ?> - &pound; <?=$course->course_cost; ?>
                                    </a>
                                    <a class="course-btn pull-right" href="<?=base_url(); ?>view-course/<?=$course->course_id; ?>" title="View Course - <?=$course->course_title; ?>">
                                        View Course
                                    </a>
                            </li>
                            <? endforeach; ?>
                        </ul>
                        <? } ?>
                    <? endforeach; ?>
                </div>
        <? endforeach; ?>
    </div>

    <? } ?>

</div>
<?= $template['_partials']['user_navigation']; ?>
```

The error line is question is :

```
<?  if($course[0]->subcategory_id == $subcategory->subcategory_id) { ?>
```

Hope someone can help me out on this offset nightmare I find myself in. :-(

Comment: just a tip, you shouldn't use the shorthand `<?` or `<?=` for php tags, if ever you move to a system, or work on a system that does not support this, it will cause unnecessary hassle and or confusion. You should always use the full `<?php` tag. On topic: what line does that error occur?

Comment: what you mean by `$course[0]->subcategory_id ?`

Comment: Is $course actually an array? Perhaps you mean `$course->subcategory_id`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to specify `[0]` when you are using `foreach` loop. try

```
<?php if($course->subcategory_id == $subcategory->subcategory_id) { ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
if($course[0]->subcategory_id == $subcategory->subcategory_id) { ?>
```

It seems like you are trying to access to first element in array but you are already looping and it's not needed

```
if($course->subcategory_id == $subcategory->subcategory_id) { ?>
```

As side not I think you should really use php long tags `<?php .... ?>` instead of short ones `<?...?>`

Comment: Thanks for that @Fabio I will start using the long tags from now on too.